# Import an IntelliJ IDEA project into NetBeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, import, intellij-idea

How can I import an IntelliJ IDEA project into Netbeans?

I know I can just use IntelliJ but I prefer Netbeans...

With this particular project I can't just copy the source directory into a Netbeans project... That doesn't work?

How may I use this IntelliJ IDEA project within Netbeans?

Comment: Export an Eclipse project in IDEA, use the Eclipse import plugin in Netbeans.

Comment: how large is the project? does it have many dependencies, artifacts? maybe you'd better ask a question about creating a Netbens project from sources? and why would someone choose Netbeans over IDEA?

Comment: Netbeans is like a thin layer between your code and you. Where as eclipse is its morbidly obese cousin and Idea seems to be on the thicker side too.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Does that method actually work, or was that just thinking out loud?  I'd really like to know how to do this.

Comment: IntelliJ has "File->Export to Eclipse".  Netbeans has File -> Import Project -> Eclipse project.  I have not tried this myself.  Today I would say "redo as a maven project and open whereever you want".

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen, does maven works better with a dev computer not connected to Internet? just a side note, in most big finance companies no dev system is connected to Internet.

Comment: @AaA Maven works the best with Internet access. If you don't have that you need to pull the needed artifacts in house and use them. A bit cumbersome but doable.

Answer (score 5):

The `nbproject` is a required folder by NetBeans, where it keeps its project settings. The only necessary project build files needed are the `project.xml` and `project.properties`.

In `project.xml`, line 5 is changed to reflect the accurate name of the user's project. Also for IntelliJ, `nbintellij.iml` is the required file.

So for a IntelliJ project, if you create the `nbproject` folder with the required files (`project.xml` and `project.properties`), you'll be able to open the folder in NetBeans

---

You can use the following tool I've created to convert an IntelliJ project to NetBeans, and also convert a NetBeans project to IntelliJ. Please make sure you have python installed.

h[ttps://github.com/devanshkaloti/IDEProjectConverter-Java](https://github.com/devanshkaloti/IDEProjectConverter-Java)

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: I don't believe such a tool exists.

Longer answer: You probably should not be relying on a proprietary format for your project.  Depending on the project, [Ant+Ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/) or [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) may be a better solution.

Comment: Agree 100%. IMO, ant + ivy only goes so far. Eclipse, Netbeans and Idea all setup projects differently when using ant. Unless there is a strong company wide culture, it is hard to achieve this at work. If it is a personal project, then ofcourse there is no excuse.

Answer (score 1):

Just install the [netbeans-exporter plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/14275-netbeans-exporter) and it'll enable the `Export to NetBeans` option

What it does is to generate the `nbproject` folder.